# Render mySql data using handlebars.js

Tags: mysql, express, handlebars.js

When I try to render the 'sqlData' object array as an html table, no data is displayed; just the buttons. There are empty spaces in the rows where the data should be.

This is the relevant part of app.js, the server

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM Users', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    else {
        var sqlData = [];
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].hasOwnProperty("prim_key" && "username" && "hash")) {
                let sqlRow = {
                    key: results[i].prim_key,
                    user: results[i].username,
                    hash: results[i].hash
                }
                sqlData.push(sqlRow);
            }
        }
        exports.data = sqlData;
        console.log(sqlData);
    }
});
```

Here is my routing page, where I import the sqlData array as 'data', and attempt to render it whenever /database is visited.

```
const data = require('../app');

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/database', (req, res) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.render('database', { data });
});
```

console.logging the sqlData array after importing/before rendering it shows the following -

```
{
  data: [
    {
      key: 1,
      user: 'FakeUsername',
      hash: '$2a$08$r8MzQpj4WpAW9jnqWFlW6.geA49Gw16EkdqTBt6un4cpBxUMjUXC2'
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      user: 'NotAPassword',
      hash: '$2a$08$M0fuZ57Z3SUjoZRPrdIHJ.dc6KXuS./Di84CYAHBRNaXx7VnabkgG'
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is the relevant piece of my template file database.hbs (where I believe the problem must be?) -

```
               {{#each this}}
                <tr>
                    <td headers="key">{{key}}</td>
                    <td headers="user">{{user}}</td>
                    <td headers="hash">{{hash}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="editRow();">Edit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="deleteRow();">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
```

Here's a screenshot of what is being rendered in the browser. Please note that the 2 populated rows is placeholder html I used to get the styles correct, it is not actual data from the sqlData array.

Something that may be noteworthy is that there are six objects in my sqlData array, and only 4 rows have been rendered in the browser.

[image]

Comment: I am  a little confused about what the value of `data` is, but it looks like your template should have either `{{#each this.data}}` or `{{#each this.data.data}}`.

Answer (score 0):

76484 Was right, {{#each this.data.data}} fixed my issue. I must have done something wrong for that to be the case, since this.data.data is pretty redundant.

Comment: This is because you are assigning an object with the shape `{ data: [] }` to be the `data` property of a new object when you do `{ data }`. The shape of the resulting object is `{ data: { data: [] } }`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).